# rescaling for smaller screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, scale

I have designed a online magazine with turn.js that works fine , the size is A4 (842px x 595px) for screen, but when someone looks at it in smaller screens (13 ") it doesnt show all in same viewport and they have to scroll down. when i zoom out with javascript the browser even the pictures zoom out propertionally the text does not. any recommendations please how to scale a div with text propertionally smaller. 
the url to development page is here. 
http://www.lambuka.com/magazine/final-magazine.php?m_id=78

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at post

[Font size description](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem)